# JavaScript (DOM) print next prime typecasting issue

Tags: javascript, html

A friend of mine who studies Multimedia Art is given a task as part of his HTML+JavaScript homework, which is following: Make a button, which upon being clicked generates the next prime (next after the one given between a following `<p>` tags. He brought it to me to solve it and at the first glance I thought it's a very easy problem and wrote the code. But instead of printing the next prime, it printed `NaN` and now I'm not as confident as before about my simple JavaScript skills. Here's my code:

```js
function isPrime(num) {
    for (var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num) + 1; ++i) {
        if(num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return num !== 1;
}

function getNextPrime(prime) {
    for (var count = prime + 1; ; ++count) {
      if (isPrime(count)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    return count;
}

function printNextPrime() {
    var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("primePar").value);
    var next = getNextPrime(p);
    
    document.getElementById("primePar").innerHTML = next;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prime Number Generator</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head><body>
        <button onclick="printNextPrime()">Generate Next Prime!</button>
        <p id="primePar">2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I suspect the problem is about a wrong type conversion that I've done but as I scan my code carefully several times over, I'm unable to find it. Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
function printNextPrime() {
    var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("primePar").value);
    var next = getNextPrime(p);

    document.getElementById("primePar").innerHTML = next.toString();
}
```

You're looking for teh value property, but that property only exists for "input" DOM objects. Instead, you should be able to use .innerHTML there as well.

```
function printNextPrime() {
    var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("primePar").innerHTML);
    var next = getNextPrime(p);

    document.getElementById("primePar").innerHTML = next.toString();
}
```

Comment: @NimaBavari That's a logic error, I'd suggest doing some searching for next prime algorithms and seeing if you can find where it went wrong, I'm not familiar enough with the math here to know if this is the correct or best way to go about it.

Comment: I found the solution to the further problem. You have solved the issue in the main question. Thank you, +1 and accepted!